# C++ search and execute method whenever a character is spotted

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Below I have some code and in the last if statement I want to search for the letter **B**. However, I want to search from the position of where **P** was found and increment until it finds **B** and then when it finds **B** I want to execute a method.

I have used a comment in my code to show you where the code will go.

So the steps are

1. Find the position of 'P'
2. Increment from position of 'P' until you find 'B' and the execute method
3. Keep incrementing againg until you reach the end of the vector and if you see a 'B' again execute the same method again and so on

The code I have so far is:

```
std::vector<std::string> order;
std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
std::vector<std::string> tempOrder;

order.push_back("V"); //V
order.push_back("I");//F
order.push_back("F");//I
order.push_back("N");//O
order.push_back("D");//O
order.push_back("W");//O
order.push_back("O");//O
order.push_back("P");//O
order.push_back("Y");//O
order.push_back("B");//O
order.push_back("L");//O
order.push_back("B");//O
order.push_back("R");//O
order.push_back("X");//O

if(order.front() == "V")
{
    it = find(order.begin(), order.end(), "I");
    ++it;
    std::string o = *it;
    DCS_LOG_DEBUG("NEXT 0 " << o);
    DCS_LOG_DEBUG("NEXT " << *it);


    int i = find(order.begin(), order.end(), "N") - order.begin();
    int pos = i;

    DCS_LOG_DEBUG("POS " << pos);

    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < pos; i1++)
    {
        //DCS_LOG_DEBUG("IN LINE " << order[i1]);

        if(order[i1] == "D" || order[i1] == "W" || order[i1] == "O" || order[i1] == "P")
        {
            DCS_LOG_DEBUG("It matches one of the above incorrect");

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            DCS_LOG_DEBUG("OK");
            break;
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string>secondOrder;
    copy(order.begin() +  pos + 1, order.end(), std::back_inserter(secondOrder));


    if(find(secondOrder.begin(), secondOrder.end(),"P")- secondOrder.begin())
    {
        DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Found");
        int i1 = find(order.begin(), order.end(), "P") - order.begin();

        //HERE IS WHERE THE CODE WILL GO

    }
    else
    {
        DCS_LOG_DEBUG("NOT FOUND");
    }

}
```

Comment: Y dont your code have any iterator? Wont that make it easier to traverse?

Answer (score 0):

So put the second logic inside a loop that executes until it reaches the end of the `vector`:

```
 if( (it = find(secondOrder.begin(), secondOrder.end(),"P") ) != secondOrder.end() )
 {
      DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Found");
      it1 = order.begin();
      while ( (it1 = find(it1, order.end(), "B")) != order.end() )
      {
         //code here
         //*it1 is the element you're looking for
      }
 }
 else
 {
      DCS_LOG_DEBUG("NOT FOUND");
 }
```

Note that I'm using iterators, not indexes.

Also, your indentation is awful.

EDIT: I see you changed your code since I answered the question. The logic remains the same.

Comment: Sorry where does it `it1` come from, and i would loop from the position of where **P** was to the end of **secondOrder** not from **order.begin()**

Comment: @ShamariCampbell `it1` is an iterator for `order`. Also, as you weren't very explicit in your question, I merely provided the logic. Feel free to change the names as you see fit.

Comment: @ Luchian Grigore: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9530751/1155650 the user reposted the question

Comment: @Rohit I know, I voted to close. He's clearly not making an effort himself. I, for one, will not provide a full solution.

Comment: i am making an effort i have been looking at this all night! i jsut did not think the answer was close to what i wanted, but anyway i shall start again at the moment i can locate the first **B** and the go to the end of the vector but whenever the iterator finds another letter it will output my error statement many times i just want it to output once :) ? @LuchianGrigore

Comment: @ Luchian Grigore: i have been busy all day and didnt get time to look at it. If you can just help him out with what his actual trouble is!

Comment: @ShamariCampbell can you edit the question with the new code you have, and tell us exactly where the problem is?